# Selenium is not opening site?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i try to open this website using selenium: https://www.landnsea.net/
(opening by hand in chrome either in normal mode and incognito mode is possible)

this is the code im using

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  HEADERS = {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
  }

  link = "https://www.landnsea.net"  
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
  path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
  if platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
  elif platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver'
  elif platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
  driver.get (link)
```

When i am running the program the site opens but i don´t get to the login screen.

Why is opening this page not working with selenium?

I think this is the part where the checking is done - i read this out with BeautifulSoup:

```
<div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
 <noscript>
  <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">
   Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.
  </h1>
 </noscript>
 <div id="cf-content" style="display: block;">
  <div id="cf-bubbles">
   <div class="bubbles">
   </div>
   <div class="bubbles">
   </div>
   <div class="bubbles">
   </div>
  </div>
  <h1>
   <span data-translate="checking_browser">
    Checking your browser before accessing
   </span>
   www.landnsea.net.
  </h1>
  <div class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" id="no-cookie-warning" style="display:none">
   <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">
    Please enable Cookies and reload the page.
   </p>
  </div>
  <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">
   This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
  </p>
  <p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs">
   Please allow up to 5 seconds…
  </p>
  <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">
   Redirecting…
  </p>
 </div>
 <form action="/mov/login.htm?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_HaWZ4vSGjaTyyRdgUT6W6hapfCN9Am.Q_fYMeTph8wk-1634374280-0-gqNtZGzNAjujcnBszQgR" class="challenge-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
  <input name="md" type="hidden" value="ckruH4cMo_91RT4vrBFz9ds90Pw_fBJMradIMGbBHf4-1634374280-0-Ae1p781nAPfJ-_E0d7q6_cdATkWhuty8I-_BWQk6bL49Qe_TXshaNWVJdiH8ro4tHwuGXFzSpFMbVcgTEuDaz7DeIgcRTKixvmgqJ__B6tp6osrP35Om_XkDbaFXaXHrV4x-28tuaE9lw-l9EczBeeGXyVl28Xgr12KlM7MRyp9EJ3KMdtpd3dbqajToAwj3F5LeINMtQxmiypDYtZ-hbZCY11RmpwWgy7HwPMUe8Hmpcp4vKaVnYTNUwDVYM76VOD-svmIknjwHW0f1VuiWLXtiI5iv1_2l6Q24kEjyLR3vFh3yRJ3puc4Oo8NwAi3EhSNJvlRUvdGXaVf8ZbGImhyPpy1fK3G6r_MwNY5mMoZVdMtj73ORB7Wnb1AvqupxhneevgfwlDo7RXUy7yaReKx4dJS4TCiI4UReE6sc6G9nlxg9LINDHLPlHOMq4s2i1Ek8taAx9mbpavOcpdvAZW2q3BGG3KZ8O5BNnUKW-XFojaTc2juvwuiBdvRqvFJCKA"/>      
  <input name="r" type="hidden" value="_d2eLttCt_xKBhyiWnBQTHdk8jVLaIQHb64tfgWg4oo-1634374280-0-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"/>
  <input id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc" type="hidden" value="fe2d1755e23f31387c92b3046378a830"/>
  <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/> -->
  <input name="pass" type="hidden" value="1634374281.028-mQ3i5gRSbj"/>
  <input id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer" type="hidden"/>
  <span style="display:none">
   error code: 1020
  </span>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      (function(){
          var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
          a.style.display = 'block';
          var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
          var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
          trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/js/transparent.gif?ray=69f00b722f601a30");
          trkjs.id = "trk_jschal_js";
          trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
          document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
          var cpo=document.createElement('script');
          cpo.type='text/javascript';
          cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=69f00b722f601a30";
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
      //]]>
 </script>
 <div id="trk_jschal_nojs" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=69f00b722f601a30')">
 </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE - tried some solutions from the comments below

(1) create a new chrome-profile and login before the selenium start
(not working - same result as before)

```
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile1") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
  options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
  path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
  if platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
  elif platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver'
  elif platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
  srv=Service(path + cd)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)
  driver.get (link)
  time.sleep (60)
```

(2) tried the undetected-chromdriver module
(not working - same result as before)

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get (link)
```

Comment: The website has a sort of checking page before it actually opens the login page. That could be the issue.

Comment: So its impossible to get this automated with selenium? I have the credentials but i cant get to the page were i can input them...
(and was is also irritating me that it still works in the incognito mode fine - normally when there are some problems they are also in the incognito mode of chrome)

Comment: I think the website can detect the driver and won't let you in. I would try some sort of hiding mode

Comment: What do you mean with "hiding mode"?

Comment: Also it would be no problem to do the very first login step manually - and do all the later automatisation then.

Comment: If you can do the first step manually, I would suggest to use a Chrome Profile, login for the first time so the website save the cookies and then you can load the Chrome profile you have used on the Chrome Driver and navigate as it will keep the login session open

Comment: If you are okay with using an external library, you can try the [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like, you could increase the wait time in case the cloudflare check is longer

```
driver.get(url)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        driver.get_element_by_id(your_id)
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: ok thanks - but what id should i use for your_id in that case?

Comment: You could also use a xpath if your element has no id. just right click on the username or password textbox and click on copy xpath. Instead of get_element_by_id you use get_element_by_xpath(your_xpath)

Comment: It´s not about the id - the problem is i didn´t get to this page where i can enter user and pw